# Android : Specifying the same Theme in styles.xml and styles-21.xml

Tags: android, material-design

When we want to include material design with back ward compatibility in our app, we use the `appcompat` library.

I tried doing it by including this in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

But when I do this, I don't see any ripples on touching widgets (even in android L phones).

**Why is that?**

And when I put the same above line in both `styles.xml` and `styles-21.xml`, I can see the ripples in `Android L` phones.
If the support library does not include ripples, how I am able to see the ripples when I have a separate `styles-v21`  file?

**Note:** I came across this issue when I was trying to migrate my app to material design.

I want app to be using the full capabilities of the `Support Library for Material design` when running on devices below Android L and I want the app to use the full power of `Material design` when running on Android L and above. I am not sure how I should proceed about migrating.

Comment: What version of the support library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The API 21+ device will first look into styles-v21 and then into styles as a fallback.